# what are the available events in a CompositeView in Marionette backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I cannot find documented the available events colllectionEvents which I can listen to in a CompositeView.

```
 collectionEvents: {
    "all": "myFunc",
    "add": "myFunc",
    }
```

The above are called for each model being updated.

I am calling fetch on the collection associated with the View and i want to know when the whole collection is updated.

Thanks

--JustinWyllie

Answer (score 0):

Use the "reset" event. The events used are the ones provided by Backbone, which you can find here: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: Thanks David. That's really useful. It was the sync event. I also discovered that if you handle the 'all' event the first param passed to the function is the name of the event so you can see what gets fired when.